# Keeping a client object model connection open

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-clientobject

I am writing a WPF app which needs to check a SharePoint list about every minute. It will be doing this from about a thousand machines. I'll probably try to put some intelligence in there to reduce the number of machines doing updates (check to see if the screen saver is running if possible. Check to see if the computer is idle. Don't update in either of these cases)

What is the load of having a thousand computers hit a SP2010 sever with Client Object Model connections? Should I just have them all establish a connection, and then keep it open constantly? Or should I re-establish a connection every minute, download the data, and close the connection? I'm having trouble figuring out with the cost of these operations will be on a large scale.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SP2010 client object model uses OOBT services which scales well and you don't have to worry too much while relaying on them. [Start here to analyze in more detail](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/ff601870.aspx)

Other solution to consider:
consider [duplex services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731064.aspx) by which you can convert your poll mechanism to push. There are certain limitation, make sure it is useful in your scenario. Here are additional links for your reference:

http://www.eggheadcafe.com/tutorials/wcf/b5ada8df-58c5-492f-b368-457b3a4f137c/notify-client-
applications-using-wcf-callbacks.aspx

Comment: So when you say "scales well" and "don't have to worry while relying on them", opening a connection and keeping it open is fine?

And it looks like the duplex service uses WCF. I already wrote a WCF service that I use to hit a common logging service that a coworker wrote. So it would be fairly trivial for me to set that up. You think have 1000 or so open WCF connections, using Push via duplex services, would not cause a problem?